# Ajax call not appending data to tfoot elements (but works properly in thead elements)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have several select inputs in a row inside of my table (for column filtering) that populate options through ajax responses using jquery. They are currently in a second thead and append properly, but I would like to move them into a tfoot instead.

Currently I have this ajax call, and it properly appends the data when my elements are inside a thead:

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "?handler=loadDropdowns",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        async: true,
        success: function (response) 
        {
            $("#requesttos").empty().append('<option>All</option>');
            $("#requesttos").append('<option selected>' + response.user + '</option>');
            $.each(response.requesttos, function (index, value) {
                $("<option/>", {
                    value: index,
                    text: value
                }).appendTo($("#requesttos"));
            });
            
            $("#groups").empty().append('<option selected>All</option>');
            $.each(response.groups, function (index, value) {
                $("<option/>", {
                    value: index,
                    text: value
                }).appendTo($("#groups"));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

However, once I switch it to a tfoot, nothing populates anymore :( Why does my ajax response properly load when my elements are in a thead, but moving to a tfoot doesn't load anything at all?

Here's my full table (shortened for simplicity):

```html
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped nowrap w-100" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Request To
                </th>
                <th>
                    Group
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
<!--tbody is populated w/ server-side DataTable-->
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <select id="requesttos"></select>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <select id="groups"></select>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

EDIT: This has something to do with my DataTable overriding what's being appended! I'll continue to test for a fix. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any element with requestto id in your HTML, only one with id requesttos

Comment: @LaurentS. Typo in my question - Fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Your original one works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/wf5o4tp9/ The other selectors are not configured correctly based on css selector rules

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong... id's are supposed to be unique, hence `$('#requesttos')` is more than enough to identify uniquely this element in your DOM.

Please note that if this id is NOT unique, only the first element to appear in the dom with this id will be returned.

Comment: Makes sense, it must be something else. All I do is switch my second <thead> to <tfoot> and bam, nothing populates anymore.

Comment: if you use only this id selector, and you should definitely not need anything more, you shouldn't care at all where this element is. It can be directly in the body, it can be under 1000 parents, it will trigger.